# how to optimise the java memory

Tags: java, memory, optimization

i write a java server, and it takes too much memory that I have to optimise it. I analyse the program, it only scan some data, then parse it and write it to the file. It takes about 2GB RES, but i cal the real data and it should be round 300MB. So I use JProfiler to optimise the programme. I have found that it frees memory about 0.6GB. At first I propose that maybe the arraylist should be use ensureCapacity and be a class member to avoid too much new operations. I test with the following code, astonishing that it also frees the about 40MB all the time[image]. So What should I do, if want to minimise the memory usage.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayListTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ArrayList<Integer> t = new ArrayList<Integer>(100);
    while (true) {

    // System.out.println(t.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
      t.add(i);
    }    
    // System.out.println(t.size());

    t.clear();
    // System.out.println(t.size());
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to upload the live memory picture of 2

Comment: IIRC, Java never returns memory to the OS...

Comment: I use JProfiler to attach the program and see the memory result given in picture

Comment: Really? Who would have guessed that... ;) What I was trying to say is that when memory never gets returned to the OS by the VM, you may use it instead of trying to optimize it. Let's say your startup needs 200MB. There simply is no good point trying to reduce your server's memory footprint while running since the 200MB are taken by the JVM and never be returned.